# Installation of python3.6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 - python3 --version still shows 3.4.3

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python3

I'm trying to install the latest python on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've tried to do the following so far:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

it's finished successfully.

when I enter:

```
ls /usr/bin | grep python
```

I'm getting:

```
dh_python2
dh_python3
python
python2
python2.7
python3
python3.4
python3.4-config
python3.4m
python3.4m-config
python3.6
python3.6m
python3-config
python3m
python3m-config
python-mkdebian
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.4-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.4m-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config
```

as I can see, there is a Python 3.6. But when I type:

```
python3 --version
```

I'm getting

```
Python 3.4.3
```

Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is working as intended. If you want to use Python 3.6, run `python3.6`.

Comment: For anyone who's getting `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found` when trying the first command, you have to `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` first.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't do anything wrong and things are working as intended. Even after you have installed Python 3.6 from a PPA, the `/usr/bin/python3` symlink on your Ubuntu 14.04 system still points to `/usr/bin/python3.4`, not `/usr/bin/python3.6`. Therefore, to invoke the Python 3.6 interpreter, you explicitly run `python3.6`.

I would highly discourage you from changing the `/usr/bin/python3` symlink to point to `/usr/bin/python3.4` because there is probably a significant number of programs in Ubuntu that rely on Python 3 being actually Python 3.4 and you risk breaking these programs by making the symlink point to Python 3.6.